# Vue Data not displaying in the DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am building a weather station app using VueJS, and am trying to add forecast data from the OpenWeather API. I can successfully pull down the data and log it to the console, but for some reason I can't display it in the template.

I am grabbing the next five hours of data and storing it in arrays. At the moment I am just trying to display the first hour. Here's my code:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <h1>Forecast</h1>

        <i :class="['owf owf-',iconCode[0]]"></i>
        <p>Temperature {{ currentTemp[0] }}</p>

    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
      data: function(){
        return {
          time: [],
          currentTemp: [],
          tempMin: [],
          desc: [],
          iconCode: [],
        }
      },

      methods: {
          getWeather() {
            var apiKey = "<apikey>";
            var location = "<location>";
            var units = "metric";
            var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + location + "&APPID=" + apiKey + "&units=" + units;
            this.$http.get(url).then(response => {
              console.log(response.data.list);
              for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                this.time[i] = response.data.list[i].dt_txt;
                this.currentTemp[i] = response.data.list[i].main.temp;
                this.tempMin[i] = response.data.list[i].main.temp_min;
                this.desc[i] = response.data.list[i].weather[0].description;
                this.iconCode[i] = response.data.list[i].weather[0].icon;
              }
            });
          },
      },

      beforeMount(){
        this.getWeather();
      },
  }
</script>
```

This successfully grabs the data I want and populates the variables (verified in Vue Dev Tools). The template is injected into the page successfully and the static text is displayed. But the data isn't displayed. What gives?

EDIT: I should mention that I am using Laravel for the back end. I have tried prefacing the {{ }} with an @ symbol to tell Blade that there's JS involved, but it just displays the @ and not the variable.

Comment: Perhaps the template is rendering before the data is received. You could try using a v-if on your <p> element...

Comment: v-if=“currentTemp”

Comment: @TJWeems Just tried it... no dice :/

Comment: @TJWeems Ah, but if I use v-if="currentTemp[0]" it doesn't render the <p> tag...

Comment: could you try displaying a hard coded variable from your data object? like add variable called `test: 'test'` and add it to your template like so `{{ test }}` and see if your template displays it

Comment: @TJWeems yes, that works.

Comment: can you see if you can `console.log(this.currentTemp)` after the variable is set in your method?

Comment: @TJWeems yes, all the variables are set as expected.

Comment: can you share an image or example of what the data structure looks like from the console?

Comment: @TJWeems I'm pretty sure the data structure is fine. It's loading properly as I can see it in Vue Dev Tools.

Comment: I am curious if you are accessing the data properly from currentTemp array, which is why I was wondering what the data structure looks like. Just because it appears in Vue dev tools does not mean you are accessing it properly when trying to display it. you could just try doing `{{ currentTemp }}` and see if that displays anything..

Comment: @TJWeems hmm... `{{ currentTemp }}` renders `[]`...

Comment: @TJWeems and if I set currentTemp to ['testing'] in the data object, it returns that... so something screwy is going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the getWeather method you can't use array[i] = "value".
This is because this kind of object mutation is not tracked.

Use array.push("value") instead.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Regards

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want this.time[i], this.currentTemp[i], ...

your Loop before

```
for(var a=0 a<5;a++){
 this.time[a] = '';
 this.currentTemp[a] = '';
 .....
}
```